# Write cycles material node output to image file

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

How can I write output of a Node/Node Group in Cycles Render to the file (PNG or something else)? I saw a special File Output Node, but I can't find in Search <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>).

Answer (score 2):

The File Output node is a *compositor* node, not a Cycles material node - so it will only output the results of the actual render, not that particular material.

To output the shader results to an image you need to look into unwrapping your mesh and *baking* the material to an image.